# Cреднее значение из 3 чисел

Tags: c#

Метод должен возвращать только среднее (медиану) значение из 3 чисел, т. е отбрасывать максимальное и минмальное, а он всегда возвращает переменную "c".  Как быть? Спасибо за ответы. Вот здесь код:

```
public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(MiddleOf(5, 0, 100)); // => 5
        Console.WriteLine(MiddleOf(12, 12, 11)); // => 12
        Console.WriteLine(MiddleOf(2, 3, 2)); // => 2
        Console.WriteLine(MiddleOf(8, 8, 8)); // => 8
        Console.WriteLine(MiddleOf(5, 0, 1)); // => 1
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    public static int MiddleOf(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        if ((a > b) && (b > c)) return b;
        else if ((a > c) && (b > a)) return a;
        else return c;

    }
```

Comment: у тебя не хватает парных условий, например, для первого случая: `((a > b) && (b > c))` должна быть пара `((c > b) && (b > a))` так как результат зависит от направление сравнения. Проще всего поместить данные переменные в массив или список, отсортировать его - и взять элемент с индексом 1

Answer (score 2):

Можно делать через сравнения. Но в этом случае нужно будет проверять кучу условий. Да и запутаться очень легко. Но есть простой способ. Нужно отсортировать данные и взять средний элемент. Можно конечно использовать стандартный sort, но думаю, для трех элементов это будет перебор - поэтому отсортируем ручками (три сравнения, быстрее все равно не выйдет).

```
using System;

public class Test
{
public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(MiddleOf(5, 0, 100)); // => 5
        Console.WriteLine(MiddleOf(12, 12, 11)); // => 12
        Console.WriteLine(MiddleOf(2, 3, 2)); // => 2
        Console.WriteLine(MiddleOf(8, 8, 8)); // => 8
        Console.WriteLine(MiddleOf(5, 0, 1)); // => 1
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void Swap<T>(ref T lhs, ref T rhs)
    {
        T temp;
        temp = lhs;
        lhs = rhs;
        rhs = temp;
     }

    public static int MiddleOf(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        if (a > b) Swap<int>(ref a, ref b);
        if (a > c) Swap<int>(ref a, ref c);
        if (b > c) Swap<int>(ref b, ref c);
        return b;
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

namespace projectvisualstudio_test_stack_over
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(MiddleOf(5, 0, 100)); // => 5
            Console.WriteLine(MiddleOf(12, 12, 11)); // => 12
            Console.WriteLine(MiddleOf(2, 3, 2)); // => 2
            Console.WriteLine(MiddleOf(8, 8, 8)); // => 8
            Console.WriteLine(MiddleOf(5, 0, 1)); // => 1

            Console.WriteLine("-"); // =>

            Console.WriteLine(MiddleOf(1, 2, 3)); // => 2
            Console.WriteLine(MiddleOf(1, 3, 2)); // => 2
            Console.WriteLine(MiddleOf(2, 1, 3)); // => 2
            Console.WriteLine(MiddleOf(2, 3, 1)); // => 2
            Console.WriteLine(MiddleOf(3, 1, 2)); // => 2
            Console.WriteLine(MiddleOf(3, 2, 1)); // => 2
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        public static int MiddleOf(int a, int b, int c)
        {
            if (a < b)
            {
                if (b < c)
                {
                    return b;
                }
                else if (a > c)
                {
                    return a;
                }
                else return c;
            }
            else if (a > b)
            {
                if (a < c)
                {
                    return a;
                }
                else if(b > c)
                {
                    return b;
                }
                else return c;
            }
            else return a;


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А можно ещё `public static int MiddleOf(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e)`?

Comment: Автору темы не требуется. Кажется задание учебное.

Answer (score 0):

черт,как у вас всех все сложно то!

```
    public static int MiddleOf(params int[] abc)
    {
        if(abc.Length != 3) throw new Exception("wrong items count"); 

        Array.Sort(abc);
        return abc[1];
    }
```

Comment: Замените магическую `1` на половину длины, и проверку длины на 0 вместо трёх - и будет норм.

Comment: Именно такой способ был предложен @KoVadim, только реализация сортировки другая